# Source that Song of Songs was spoken by the Cherubs in the temple

Tags: sources-mekorot, malach-angel, shir-hashirim

In a sermon on Passover a guest Rabbi stated that Song of Songs was actually the conversation spoken by the Cherubs in the Holy of Holies. He quoted a 'Rabbi Heller' in the latter's introduction to a commentary on Song of Songs. Is there another source for this idea, alternatively who is this Rabbi Heller and what is the name of his commentary?

Comment: I'd 'a' guessed [this one](//he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%99%D7%95%D7%9D-%D7%98%D7%95%D7%91_%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%A4%D7%9E%D7%9F_%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%A8) but he doesn't seem to have written a commentary on Song of Songs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From searching I was able to find the source in the commentary [Ote Or](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/6138) on Shir Hashirim by [Rabbi Yechiel Heller](http://jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/7537-heller-jehiel-b-aaron).

In [his introduction](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=6138&st=&pgnum=8) he says, based on [Zohar Shemot 143a](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Zohar.2.143a.8?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he) and [Shir Hashirim Rabba to 1:1](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shir_HaShirim_Rabbah.1.1.5?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he), that the song was said on the day that Solomon brought the ark into the Holy of Holies. According to [Yoma 54a](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=6&daf=54&format=pdf), the cherubs were male and female and represent the love between God and Israel: When there was love between Israel and God they would face each other, and when there wasn't they would face away from each other. Thus he says that the song was said by Solomon as if it were a conversation between the cherubs on top of the ark.